# Any faster way to check if lists in a list are equivalent?

Tags: r, list, algorithm, performance, if-statement

Here I have integers `1:7` for four different partitions, i.e., {1}, {2,3,4}, {5,6}, and {7} and those partitions are written in a list, i.e., `list(1,c(2,3,4),c(5,6),7)`. I treat the partitions as sets, such that different permutation of elements within one partition should be recognized as the same one. For example, `list(1,c(2,3,4),c(5,6),7)` and `list(7,1,c(2,3,4),c(6,5))` are equivalent.

Note that, there is *no repetition* for elements in list, e.g., no `list(c(1,2),c(2,1),c(1,2))`, since this problem is discussing exclusive partitions over the whole set.

I listed some of the different permutations into the list `lst` as below

```
lst <- list(list(1,c(2,3,4),c(5,6),7),
            list(c(2,3,4),1,7,c(5,6)),
            list(1,c(2,3,4),7,c(6,5)),
            list(7,1,c(3,2,4),c(5,6)))
```

and what I want to do is to verify all permutations are equivalent. If yes, then we get result `TRUE`.

What I did so far is to sort the elements within each partition, and used `setdiff()` with `interset()` and `union()` to judge it (see my code below)

```
s <- Map(function(v) Map(sort,v),lst)
equivalent <- length(setdiff(Reduce(union,s),Reduce(intersect,s),))==0
```

However, I guess this method would be slow whenever the partition size scales up. Is there any faster approach to make it? Appreciated in advance!

- ***some test cases*** (small size data)

```
# should return `TRUE`
lst1 <- list(list(1,c(2,3,4),c(5,6)),
            list(c(2,3,4),1,c(5,6)),
            list(1,c(2,3,4),c(6,5)))

# should return `TRUE`
lst2 <- list(list(1:2, 3:4), list(3:4, 1:2))

# should return `FALSE`
lst3 <- list(list(1,c(2,3,4),c(5,6)), list(c(2,3,4),1,c(5,6)), list(1,c(2,3,5),c(6,4)))
```

Comment: I guess you  can avoid the multiple `Map` calls

Comment: `all(duplicated(lapply(lst, function(x) lapply(x, sort)))[-1])` in case you don't permute the partitions.

Comment: `all(duplicated(lapply(lst, function(x) lapply(x, sort)[order(unlist(lapply(x, length)))]))[-1])`  in case you permute the partitions.

Comment: @akrun Thanks! I did an assignment `s <- Map(function(v) Map(sort,v),lst)`, just using `Map` twice now in my edited post

Comment: I'd suggest adding a few more test cases to your question, one with equal-sized partitions, `lst_equal = list(list(1:2, 3:4), list(3:4, 1:2))` and also one where the result should be `FALSE`, maybe `lst_false <- list(list(1,c(2,3,4),c(5,6)),
            list(c(2,3,4),1,c(5,6)),
            list(1,c(2,3,5),c(6,4)))`

Comment: @Gregor Thanks for advice, now the example is edited with equal-sized partitions

Comment: I'd strongly recommend having multiple small examples - including some where the expected result is `FALSE`. That way, when an answer works on some, but not all, test cases, it's easy to diagnose why. When there's only a single example, you lose nuance in the test results. It's also nice to add new examples rather than change existing examples under people who have already worked on them.

Comment: I want to add a comment that your description makes me think that you *expect* the result to be TRUE, you're just verifying it. If this were not the case (e.g., if you think you will get a significant number of FALSEs), and especially if the length of `lst` is potentially long, you might gain efficiency with other approaches. E.g., a first check that `length(unique(lengths(lst))) == 1` would very quickly return `FALSE` if any of the inner lists have the wrong number of elements....

Comment: If that passes, you could might want to go one item at a time through `lst`, comparing `lst[[i]]` to `lst[[1]]`, and that way you can stop as soon as you find a mismatch, rather than doing all comparisons. If `lst` is long and `FALSE`s are common, this could be a big efficiency gain, but probably not worth it otherwise.

Comment: @Gregor Yes, I just want to verify it, and your idea will improve the performance for sure. I will reflect your comments to my benchmark to see the how much gain it is.

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding sorry just one more qn. can elements be repeated? e.g. `lst5 <- list(list(c(1,2), c(1,2)), list(c(2,1), c(2,1)))`

Comment: @chinsoon12 no repetitions since it denotes exclusive partitions of the whole set...I will add this to my post

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A post about `R` and any variant of ***fast*** isn't complete without a solution featuring [rcpp](/questions/tagged/rcpp).

To maximize efficiency, picking the correct data structure will be of utmost importance. Our data structure needs to store unique values and also have fast insert/access. This is exactly what [std::unordered_set](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) embodies. We only need to determine how we can uniquely identify each `vector` of unordered `integers`.

### Enter the [Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic)

The FTA states that every number can be uniquely represented (up to the **order** of the factors) by the product of primes numbers.

Here is an example demonstrating how we can use the FTA to quickly decipher if two vectors are equivalent up to order (N.B. `P` below is a list of primes numbers... `(2, 3, 5, 7, 11, etc.)`:

```
                   Maps to                    Maps to              product
vec1 = (1, 2, 7)    -->>    P[1], P[2], P[7]   --->>   2,  3, 17     -->>   102
vec2 = (7, 3, 1)    -->>    P[7], P[3], P[1]   --->>  17,  5,  2     -->>   170
vec3 = (2, 7, 1)    -->>    P[2], P[7], P[1]   --->>   3, 17,  2     -->>   102
```

From this, we see that `vec1` and `vec3` correctly map to the same number, whereas `vec2` gets mapped to a different value.

Since our actual vectors may contain up to a hundred integers less than 1000, applying the FTA will yield extremely large numbers. We can get around this by taking advantage of the product rule of logarithm:

> ***log<sub>b</sub>(xy) = log<sub>b</sub>(x) + log<sub>b</sub>(y)***

With this at our disposal, we will be able to tackle much larger numbers example (This starts deteriorating on extremely large examples).

First, we need a simple prime number generator (N.B. We are actually generating the log of each prime number).

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]

void getNPrimes(std::vector<double> &logPrimes) {
    
    const int n = logPrimes.size();
    const int limit = static_cast<int>(2.0 * static_cast<double>(n) * std::log(n));
    std::vector<bool> sieve(limit + 1, true);
    
    int lastP = 3;
    const int fsqr = std::sqrt(static_cast<double>(limit));
    
    while (lastP <= fsqr) {
        for (int j = lastP * lastP; j <= limit; j += 2 * lastP)
            sieve[j] = false;
        
        int ind = 2;
        
        for (int k = lastP + 2; !sieve[k]; k += 2)
            ind += 2;
        
        lastP += ind;
    }
    
    logPrimes[0] = std::log(2.0);
    
    for (int i = 3, j = 1; i <= limit && j < n; i += 2)
        if (sieve[i])
            logPrimes[j++] = std::log(static_cast<double>(i));
}
```

And here is the main implementation:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
bool f_Rcpp_Hash(List x) {
    
    List tempLst = x[0];
    const int n = tempLst.length();
    int myMax = 0;

    // Find the max so we know how many primes to generate
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        IntegerVector v = tempLst[i];
        const int tempMax = *std::max_element(v.cbegin(), v.cend());
        
        if (tempMax > myMax)
            myMax = tempMax;
    }
    
    std::vector<double> logPrimes(myMax + 1, 0.0);
    getNPrimes(logPrimes);
    double sumMax = 0.0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        IntegerVector v = tempLst[i];
        double mySum = 0.0;
        
        for (auto j: v)
            mySum += logPrimes[j];
        
        if (mySum > sumMax)
            sumMax = mySum;
    }

    // Since all of the sums will be double values and we want to
    // ensure that they are compared with scrutiny, we multiply
    // each sum by a very large integer to bring the decimals to
    // the right of the zero and then convert them to an integer.
    // E.g. Using the example above v1 = (1, 2, 7) & v2 = (7, 3, 1)
    //              
    //    sum of log of primes for v1 = log(2) + log(3) + log(17)
    //                               ~= 4.62497281328427
    //
    //    sum of log of primes for v2 = log(17) + log(5) + log(2)
    //                               ~= 5.13579843705026
    //    
    //    multiplier = floor(.Machine$integer.max / 5.13579843705026)
    //    [1] 418140173
    //    
    // Now, we multiply each sum and convert to an integer
    //    
    //    as.integer(4.62497281328427 * 418140173)
    //    [1] 1933886932    <<--   This is the key for v1
    //
    //    as.integer(5.13579843705026 * 418140173)
    //    [1] 2147483646    <<--   This is the key for v2
    
    const uint64_t multiplier = std::numeric_limits<int>::max() / sumMax;
    std::unordered_set<uint64_t> canon;
    canon.reserve(n);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        IntegerVector v = tempLst[i];
        double mySum = 0.0;
        
        for (auto j: v)
            mySum += logPrimes[j];
        
        canon.insert(static_cast<uint64_t>(multiplier * mySum));
    }
    
    const auto myEnd = canon.end();
    
    for (auto it = x.begin() + 1; it != x.end(); ++it) {
        List tempLst = *it;
        
        if (tempLst.length() != n)
            return false;

        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            IntegerVector v = tempLst[j];
            double mySum = 0.0;
            
            for (auto k: v)
                mySum += logPrimes[k];
            
            const uint64_t key = static_cast<uint64_t>(multiplier * mySum);
            
            if (canon.find(key) == myEnd)
                return false;
        }
    }
    
    return true;
}
```

Here are the results when applied to `lst1, lst2, lst3, & lst (the large one)` given by @GKi.

```
f_Rcpp_Hash(lst)
[1] TRUE

f_Rcpp_Hash(lst1)
[1] TRUE

f_Rcpp_Hash(lst2)
[1] FALSE

f_Rcpp_Hash(lst3)
[1] FALSE
```

And here are some benchmarks with the `units` parameter set to `relative`.

```
microbenchmark(check = 'equal', times = 10
               , unit = "relative"
               , f_ThomsIsCoding(lst3)
               , f_chinsoon12(lst3)
               , f_GKi_6a(lst3)
               , f_GKi_6b(lst3)
               , f_Rcpp_Hash(lst3))
Unit: relative
                 expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
f_ThomsIsCoding(lst3) 84.882393 63.541468 55.741646 57.894564 56.732118 33.142979    10
   f_chinsoon12(lst3) 31.984571 24.320220 22.148787 22.393368 23.599284 15.211029    10
       f_GKi_6a(lst3)  7.207269  5.978577  5.431342  5.761809  5.852944  3.439283    10
       f_GKi_6b(lst3)  7.399280  5.751190  6.350720  5.484894  5.893290  8.035091    10
    f_Rcpp_Hash(lst3)  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000    10


microbenchmark(check = 'equal', times = 10
               , unit = "relative"
               , f_ThomsIsCoding(lst)
               , f_chinsoon12(lst)
               , f_GKi_6a(lst)
               , f_GKi_6b(lst)
               , f_Rcpp_Hash(lst))
Unit: relative
                expr        min         lq       mean     median        uq       max neval
f_ThomsIsCoding(lst) 199.776328 202.318938 142.909407 209.422530 91.753335 85.090838    10
   f_chinsoon12(lst)   9.542780   8.983248   6.755171   9.766027  4.903246  3.834358    10
       f_GKi_6a(lst)   3.169508   3.158366   2.555443   3.731292  1.902140  1.649982    10
       f_GKi_6b(lst)   2.992992   2.943981   2.019393   3.046393  1.315166  1.069585    10
    f_Rcpp_Hash(lst)   1.000000   1.000000   1.000000   1.000000  1.000000  1.000000    10
```

About **3x faster** than the fastest solution yet on the larger example.

> What does this mean?

To me, this result speaks volumes to the beauty and efficiency of `base R` as displayed by @GKi, @chinsoon12, @Gregor, @ThomasIsCoding, and more. We wrote around 100 lines of very specific `C++` to obtain a moderate speed up. To be fair, the `base R` solutions end up calling mostly compiled code and end up utilizing hash tables as we did above.

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding, I'm honored that you chose my answer, but I honestly believe the other answers are better.

Comment: Thank you very much for your contribution! Your work is excellent!

Answer (score 5):

After sorting you can use `duplicated` and `all`.

```
s <- lapply(lst, function(x) lapply(x, sort)) #Sort vectors
s <- lapply(s, function(x) x[order(vapply(x, "[", 1, 1))]) #Sort lists
all(duplicated(s)[-1]) #Test if there are all identical
#length(unique(s)) == 1 #Alternative way to test if all are identical
```

Alternative: Sort in one loop

```
s <- lapply(lst, function(x) {
  tt <- lapply(x, sort)
  tt[order(vapply(tt, "[", 1, 1))]
})
all(duplicated(s)[-1])
```

Alternative: Sort during loop and allow early exit

```
s <- lapply(lst[[1]], sort)
s <- s[order(vapply(s, "[", 1, 1))]
tt  <- TRUE
for(i in seq(lst)[-1]) {
  x <- lapply(lst[[i]], sort)
  x <- x[order(vapply(x, "[", 1, 1))]
  if(!identical(s, x)) {
    tt  <- FALSE
    break;
  }
}
tt
```

or using `setequal`

```
s <- lapply(lst[[1]], sort)
tt  <- TRUE
for(i in seq(lst)[-1]) {
  x <- lapply(lst[[i]], sort)
  if(!setequal(s, x)) {
    tt  <- FALSE
    break;
  }
}
tt
```

or improving slightly the idea from [@chinsoon12](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59282860/10488504) to exchange the list with a vector!

```
s <- lst[[1]][order(vapply(lst[[1]], min, 1))]
s <- rep(seq_along(s), lengths(s))[order(unlist(s))]
tt <- TRUE
for(i in seq(lst)[-1]) {
  x <- lst[[i]][order(vapply(lst[[i]], min, 1))]
  x <- rep(seq_along(x), lengths(x))[order(unlist(x))]
  if(!identical(s, x)) {tt <- FALSE; break;}
}
tt
```

or avoid the second `order`

```
s <- lst[[1]][order(vapply(lst[[1]], min, 1))]
s <- rep(seq_along(s), lengths(s))[order(unlist(s))]
y <- s
tt <- TRUE
for(i in seq(lst)[-1]) {
  x <- lst[[i]][order(vapply(lst[[i]], min, 1))]
  y <- y[0]
  y[unlist(x)] <- rep(seq_along(x), lengths(x))
  if(!identical(s, y)) {tt <- FALSE; break;}
}
tt
```

or exchange `order` with `match` (or `fmatch`)

```
x <- lst[[1]]
s <- "[<-"(integer(),unlist(x),rep(seq_along(x), lengths(x)))
s <- match(s, unique(s))
tt <- TRUE
for(i in seq(lst)[-1]) {
  x <- lst[[i]]
  y <- "[<-"(integer(),unlist(x),rep(seq_along(x), lengths(x)))
  y <- match(y, unique(y))
  if(!identical(s, y)) {tt <- FALSE; break;}
}
tt
```

Or without early exit.

```
s <- lapply(lst, function(x) {
  y <- "[<-"(integer(),unlist(x),rep(seq_along(x), lengths(x)))
  match(y, unique(y))
})
all(duplicated(s)[-1])
```

or written in C++

```
sourceCpp(code = "#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <vector>
using namespace Rcpp;
// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]
// [[Rcpp::export]]
bool f_GKi_6_Rcpp(const List &x) {
  const List &x0 = x[0];
  const unsigned int n = x0.length();
  unsigned int nn = 0;
  for (List const &i : x0) {nn += i.length();}
  std::vector<int> s(nn);
  for (unsigned int i=0; i<n; ++i) {
    const IntegerVector &v = x0[i];
    for (int const &j : v) {
      if(j > nn) return false;
      s[j-1] = i;
    }
  }
  {
    std::vector<int> lup(n, -1);
    int j = 0;
    for(int &i : s) {
      if(lup[i] < 0) {lup[i] = j++;}
      i = lup[i];
    }
  }
  for (List const &i : x) {
    if(i.length() != n) return false;
    std::vector<int> sx(nn);
    for(unsigned int j=0; j<n; ++j) {
      const IntegerVector &v = i[j];
      for (int const &k : v) {
        if(k > nn) return false;
        sx[k-1] = j;
      }
    }
    {
      std::vector<int> lup(n, -1);
      int j = 0;
      for(int &i : sx) {
        int &lupp = lup[i];
        if(lupp == -1) {lupp = j; i = j++;
        } else {i = lupp;}
      }
    }
    if(s!=sx) return false;
  }
  return true;
}
")
```

Thanks to @Gregor for hints to improve the answer!

Comment: I don't think that would work when having partitions of equal size,,,but should be faster than mine when have unequal-sized partitions. For example, `lst <- list(list(1,c(2,3,4),c(5,6),7),
            list(c(2,3,4),1,7,c(5,6)),
            list(1,c(2,3,4),7,c(6,5)),
            list(7,1,c(3,2,4),c(5,6)))` will be judged as `FALSE`

Comment: @Gregor Thanks for the tip to sort by `min`!

Comment: Looks great! I will wait a bit longer to see if there is any further faster solution.

Comment: what are the actual dimensions of your dataset for you to seek a faster solution?

Comment: I added performance benchmarks to see the efficiency (see my newly edited post). Your solution is faster than mine, particularly the two-step one. I would like to wait till any solution  with larger improvements appears, otherwise yours would be accepted as the best. Thank you again!

Comment: @chinsoon12 you can see my edited post with benchmark code, where the dataset size of interest might even bigger than that

Comment: @JosephWood Updates only for personal interest. We are in the range of *milliseconds* where differences should have most of the time no practical relevance.

Answer (score 4):

Performance:

```
library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(check = 'equal', times=10
  , f_ThomsIsCoding(lst1)
  , f_chinsoon12(lst1)
  , f_GKi_6a(lst1)
  , f_GKi_6b(lst1)
  , f_GKi_6_Rcpp(lst1)
  , f_Rcpp_Hash(lst1))
#Unit: microseconds
#                  expr        min         lq        mean     median         uq        max neval
# f_ThomsIsCoding(lst1) 161187.790 162453.520 167107.5739 167899.471 169441.028 174746.156    10
#    f_chinsoon12(lst1)  64380.792  64938.528  66983.9449  67357.924  68487.438  69201.032    10
#        f_GKi_6a(lst1)   8833.595   9201.744  10377.5844   9407.864  12145.926  14662.022    10
#        f_GKi_6b(lst1)   8815.592   8913.950   9877.4948   9112.924  10941.261  12553.845    10
#    f_GKi_6_Rcpp(lst1)    394.754    426.489    539.1494    439.644    451.375   1327.885    10
#     f_Rcpp_Hash(lst1)    327.665    374.409    499.4080    398.101    495.034   1198.674    10

microbenchmark(check = 'equal', times=10
  , f_ThomsIsCoding(lst2)
  , f_chinsoon12(lst2)
  , f_GKi_6a(lst2)
  , f_GKi_6b(lst2)
  , f_GKi_6_Rcpp(lst2)
  , f_Rcpp_Hash(lst2))
#Unit: microseconds
#                  expr       min        lq        mean      median         uq        max neval
# f_ThomsIsCoding(lst2) 93808.603 99663.651 103358.2039 104676.1600 107124.879 107485.696    10
#    f_chinsoon12(lst2)   131.320   147.192    192.5354    188.1935    205.053    337.062    10
#        f_GKi_6a(lst2)  8630.970  9554.279  10681.9510   9753.2670  11970.377  13489.243    10
#        f_GKi_6b(lst2)    39.736    47.916     61.3929     52.7755     63.026    110.808    10
#    f_GKi_6_Rcpp(lst2)    43.017    51.022     72.8736     76.3465     86.527    116.060    10
#     f_Rcpp_Hash(lst2)     3.667     4.237     20.5887     16.3000     18.031     96.728    10

microbenchmark(check = 'equal', times=10
  , f_ThomsIsCoding(lst3)
  , f_chinsoon12(lst3)
  , f_GKi_6a(lst3)
  , f_GKi_6b(lst3)
  , f_GKi_6_Rcpp(lst3)
  , f_Rcpp_Hash(lst3))
#Unit: microseconds
#                  expr        min         lq        mean      median         uq        max neval
# f_ThomsIsCoding(lst3) 157660.501 166914.782 167067.2512 167204.9065 168055.941 177153.694    10
#    f_chinsoon12(lst3)    139.157    181.019    183.9257    188.0950    198.249    211.860    10
#        f_GKi_6a(lst3)   9484.496   9617.471  10709.3950  10056.1865  11812.037  12830.560    10
#        f_GKi_6b(lst3)     33.583     36.338     47.1577     42.6540     63.469     66.640    10
#    f_GKi_6_Rcpp(lst3)     60.010     60.455     89.4963     94.7220    104.271    121.431    10
#     f_Rcpp_Hash(lst3)      4.404      5.518      9.9811      6.5115     17.396     20.090    10

microbenchmark(check = 'equal', times=10
  , f_ThomsIsCoding(lst4)
  , f_chinsoon12(lst4)
  , f_GKi_6a(lst4)
  , f_GKi_6b(lst4)
  , f_GKi_6_Rcpp(lst4)
  , f_Rcpp_Hash(lst4))
#Unit: milliseconds
#                  expr         min          lq       mean      median          uq        max neval
# f_ThomsIsCoding(lst4) 1874.129146 1937.643431 2012.99077 2002.460746 2134.072981 2187.46886    10
#    f_chinsoon12(lst4)   69.949917   74.393779   80.25362   76.595763   87.116571  100.57917    10
#        f_GKi_6a(lst4)   23.259178   23.328548   27.62690   28.856612   30.675259   32.57509    10
#        f_GKi_6b(lst4)   22.200969   22.326122   24.20769   23.023687   23.619360   31.74266    10
#    f_GKi_6_Rcpp(lst4)    8.062451    8.228526   10.30559    8.363314   13.425531   13.80677    10
#     f_Rcpp_Hash(lst4)    6.551370    6.586025    7.22958    6.724232    6.809745   11.97631    10
```

Libraries:

```
system.time(install.packages("Rcpp"))
#       User      System verstrichen 
#     27.576       1.147      29.396 

system.time(library(Rcpp))
#       User      System verstrichen 
#      0.070       0.000       0.071
```

Functions:

```
system.time({f_ThomsIsCoding <- function(lst) {
  s <- Map(function(v) Map(sort,v),lst)
  length(setdiff(Reduce(union,s),Reduce(intersect,s)))==0
}})
#       User      System verstrichen 
#          0           0           0 

#like GKi's solution to stop early when diff is detected
system.time({f_chinsoon12  <- function(lst) {
    x <- lst[[1L]]
    y <- x[order(lengths(x), sapply(x, min))]
    a <- rep(seq_along(y), lengths(y))[order(unlist(y))]
    for(x in lst[-1L]) {
        y <- x[order(lengths(x), sapply(x, min))]
        a2 <- rep(seq_along(y), lengths(y))[order(unlist(y))]
        if(!identical(a, a2)) {
            return(FALSE)
        }
    }
    TRUE
}})
#       User      System verstrichen 
#          0           0           0 

system.time({f_GKi_6a <- function(lst) {
  all(duplicated(lapply(lst, function(x) {
    y <- "[<-"(integer(),unlist(x),rep(seq_along(x), lengths(x)))
    match(y, unique(y))
  }))[-1])
}})
#      User      System verstrichen 
#          0           0           0 

system.time({f_GKi_6b <- function(lst) {
  x <- lst[[1]]
  s <- "[<-"(integer(),unlist(x),rep(seq_along(x), lengths(x)))
  s <- match(s, unique(s))
  for(i in seq(lst)[-1]) {
    x <- lst[[i]]
    y <- "[<-"(integer(),unlist(x),rep(seq_along(x), lengths(x)))
    y <- match(y, unique(y))
    if(!identical(s, y)) return(FALSE)
  }
  TRUE
}})
#       User      System verstrichen 
#          0           0           0 

system.time({sourceCpp(code = "#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <vector>
using namespace Rcpp;
// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]
// [[Rcpp::export]]
bool f_GKi_6_Rcpp(const List &x) {
  const List &x0 = x[0];
  const unsigned int n = x0.length();
  unsigned int nn = 0;
  for (List const &i : x0) {nn += i.length();}
  std::vector<int> s(nn);
  for (unsigned int i=0; i<n; ++i) {
    const IntegerVector &v = x0[i];
    for (int const &j : v) {
      if(j > nn) return false;
      s[j-1] = i;
    }
  }
  {
    std::vector<int> lup(n, -1);
    int j = 0;
    for(int &i : s) {
      if(lup[i] < 0) {lup[i] = j++;}
      i = lup[i];
    }
  }
  for (List const &i : x) {
    if(i.length() != n) return false;
    std::vector<int> sx(nn);
    for(unsigned int j=0; j<n; ++j) {
      const IntegerVector &v = i[j];
      for (int const &k : v) {
        if(k > nn) return false;
        sx[k-1] = j;
      }
    }
    {
      std::vector<int> lup(n, -1);
      int j = 0;
      for(int &i : sx) {
        int &lupp = lup[i];
        if(lupp == -1) {lupp = j; i = j++;
        } else {i = lupp;}
      }
    }
    if(s!=sx) return false;
  }
  return true;
}
")})
#       User      System verstrichen 
#      3.265       0.217       3.481 

system.time({sourceCpp(code = "#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]

void getNPrimes(std::vector<double> &logPrimes) {
    const int n = logPrimes.size();
    const int limit = static_cast<int>(2.0 * static_cast<double>(n) * std::log(n));
    std::vector<bool> sieve(limit + 1, true);
    int lastP = 3;
    const int fsqr = std::sqrt(static_cast<double>(limit));

    while (lastP <= fsqr) {
        for (int j = lastP * lastP; j <= limit; j += 2 * lastP)
            sieve[j] = false;
        int ind = 2;
        for (int k = lastP + 2; !sieve[k]; k += 2)
            ind += 2;
        lastP += ind;
    }
    logPrimes[0] = std::log(2.0);
    for (int i = 3, j = 1; i <= limit && j < n; i += 2)
        if (sieve[i])
            logPrimes[j++] = std::log(static_cast<double>(i));
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
bool f_Rcpp_Hash(List x) {
    List tempLst = x[0];
    const int n = tempLst.length();
    int myMax = 0;
    // Find the max so we know how many primes to generate
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        IntegerVector v = tempLst[i];
        const int tempMax = *std::max_element(v.cbegin(), v.cend());
        if (tempMax > myMax)
            myMax = tempMax;
    }
    std::vector<double> logPrimes(myMax + 1, 0.0);
    getNPrimes(logPrimes);
    double sumMax = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        IntegerVector v = tempLst[i];
        double mySum = 0.0;
        for (auto j: v)
            mySum += logPrimes[j];
        if (mySum > sumMax)
            sumMax = mySum;
    }
    const uint64_t multiplier = std::numeric_limits<int>::max() / sumMax;
    std::unordered_set<uint64_t> canon;
    canon.reserve(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        IntegerVector v = tempLst[i];
        double mySum = 0.0;
        for (auto j: v)
            mySum += logPrimes[j];
        canon.insert(static_cast<uint64_t>(multiplier * mySum));
    }
    const auto myEnd = canon.end();
    for (auto it = x.begin() + 1; it != x.end(); ++it) {
        List tempLst = *it;
        if (tempLst.length() != n)
            return false;
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            IntegerVector v = tempLst[j];
            double mySum = 0.0;
            for (auto k: v)
                mySum += logPrimes[k];
            const uint64_t key = static_cast<uint64_t>(multiplier * mySum);
            if (canon.find(key) == myEnd)
                return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
")})
#       User      System verstrichen 
#      3.507       0.155       3.662
```

Data:

```
lst1 <- list(list(1,c(2,3,4),c(5,6)) #TRUE
           , list(c(2,3,4),1,c(5,6))
           , list(1,c(2,3,4),c(6,5)))
lst2 <- list(list(c(2,3,4),c(1,5,6)) #FALSE
           , list(c(2,3,6),c(1,5,4))
           , list(c(2,3,4),c(1,5,6)))
lst3 <- list(list(1,c(2,3,4),c(5,6)) #FALSE
           , list(c(2,3,4),1,c(5,6))
           , list(1,c(2,3,5),c(6,4)))
set.seed(7)
N  <- 1e3
lst1 <- lst1[sample(seq(lst1), N, TRUE)]
lst2 <- lst2[sample(seq(lst2), N, TRUE)]
lst3 <- lst3[sample(seq(lst3), N, TRUE)]
N <- 1000
M <- 500
l <- unname(split(1:N,findInterval(1:N,sort(sample(1:N,N/10)),left.open = T)))
lst4 <- lapply(lapply(1:M, 
                     function(k) lapply(l, 
                                        function(v) v[sample(seq_along(v),length(v))])), function(x) x[sample(seq_along(x),length(x))])
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I just noticed that I made a typo in my code, which should be `length(setdiff(Reduce(union,s),Reduce(intersect,s)))==0 `, sorry for my mistake....

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding Answer is updated. But I made it as a Wiki, so everyone is welcome to update and include new solutions and to have this not everywhere repeated.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts! I think now my solution gives the same results as yours after correction, but slower than yours :)

Comment: @chinsoon12 thank you very much for reminding me! Now I have changed it to another of his for acception

Answer (score 3):

Hopefully 2nd time lucky

```
f <- function(lst) {
    s <- lapply(lst, function(x) {
        y <- x[order(lengths(x), sapply(x, min))]
        rep(seq_along(y), lengths(y))[order(unlist(y))]
    })
    length(unique(s))==1L
}
```

test cases:

```
# should return `TRUE`
lst1 <- list(list(1,c(2,3,4),c(5,6)),
    list(c(2,3,4),1,c(5,6)),
    list(1,c(2,3,4),c(6,5)))

# should return `TRUE`
lst2 <- list(list(1:2, 3:4), list(3:4, 1:2))

# should return `FALSE`
lst3 <- list(list(1,c(2,3,4),c(5,6)), list(c(2,3,4),1,c(5,6)), list(1,c(2,3,5),c(6,4)))

# should return `FALSE`
lst4 <- list(list(c(2,3,4),c(1,5,6)), list(c(2,3,6),c(1,5,4)), list(c(2,3,4),c(1,5,6)))

lst5 <- list(list(1,c(2,3,4),c(5,6)) #TRUE
    , list(c(2,3,4),1,c(5,6))
    , list(1,c(2,3,4),c(6,5)))
lst6 <- list(list(c(2,3,4),c(1,5,6)) #FALSE
    , list(c(2,3,6),c(1,5,4))
    , list(c(2,3,4),c(1,5,6)))
lst7 <- list(list(1,c(2,3,4),c(5,6)) #FALSE
    , list(c(2,3,4),1,c(5,6))
    , list(1,c(2,3,5),c(6,4)))
```

checks:

```
f(lst1)
#[1] TRUE
f(lst2)
#[1] TRUE
f(lst3)
#[1] FALSE
f(lst4)
#[1] FALSE
f(lst5)
#[1] TRUE
f(lst6)
#[1] FALSE
f(lst7)
#[1] FALSE
```

timing code:

```
library(microbenchmark)
set.seed(0L)
N <- 1000
M <- 100
l <- unname(split(1:N,findInterval(1:N,sort(sample(1:N,N/10)),left.open = T)))
lst <- lapply(lapply(1:M,
    function(k) lapply(l,
        function(v) v[sample(seq_along(v),length(v))])), function(x) x[sample(seq_along(x),length(x))])

f_ThomsIsCoding <- function(lst) {
    s <- Map(function(v) Map(sort,v),lst)
    length(setdiff(Reduce(union,s),Reduce(intersect,s)))==0
}

f_GKi_1 <- function(lst) {
    all(duplicated(lapply(lst, function(x) lapply(x, sort)[order(unlist(lapply(x, min)))]))[-1])
}

f_GKi_2 <- function(lst) {
    s <- lapply(lst, function(x) lapply(x, sort))
    all(duplicated(lapply(s, function(x) x[order(unlist(lapply(x, "[", 1)))]))[-1])
}


f <- function(lst) {
    s <- lapply(lst, function(x) {
        y <- x[order(lengths(x), sapply(x, min))]
        rep(seq_along(y), lengths(y))[order(unlist(y))]
    })
    length(unique(s))==1L
}

microbenchmark(times=3L,
    f_ThomsIsCoding(lst),
    f_GKi_1(lst),
    f_GKi_2(lst),
    f(lst)
)
```

timings:

```
Unit: milliseconds
                 expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval
 f_ThomsIsCoding(lst) 333.77313 334.61662 348.37474 335.46010 355.67555 375.8910     3
         f_GKi_1(lst) 324.12827 324.66580 326.33016 325.20332 327.43111 329.6589     3
         f_GKi_2(lst) 315.73533 316.05770 333.35910 316.38007 342.17099 367.9619     3
               f(lst)  12.42986  14.08256  15.74231  15.73526  17.39853  19.0618     3
```